# Stop moving other nodes while dragging one node in D3 forceSimulation

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I made a D3 forced-directed graph by `d3.forceSimulation()` and attached the drag function. While clicking one node, I don't want other nodes to move accordingly. Now I can freeze the node being dragged by setting the `d.fx` and `d.fy` as the following:

```
function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}
```

Is it possible to freeze all the other nodes while dragging one node?

Comment: just set `d.fx` and `d.fy` equal to `d.x` and `d.y` for all the other nodes

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you! I added the fixing function in the drag function and it works!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @rioV8 for the hint! I tried to fix the other nodes while dragging one node.

```
node.call(d3.drag()
    .on('start', dragstarted)
    .on('drag', dragged)
    .on('end', dragended))

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
    fix_nodes(d);
}

// Preventing other nodes from moving while dragging one node
function fix_nodes(this_node) {
    node.each(function(d){
        if (this_node != d){
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }
    });
}
```

Demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/casbie/21dvjcgn/

Comment: Is there any way to do this by not calling a function that makes other nodes move instead of iterating every node and fixing them? Your solution is correct but with very large graph the complexity increases , I am trying to avoid laggy behavior of d3 as my graph contains 5k+ nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that allows flexible manipulation on the forces of the simulation during dragging:

```
let tempForces = {};

const modifyForces = (simulation) => {
    tempForces = {};
    // For example, I want to temporarily remove the "link" and "charge" forces during dragging.
    (["link", "charge"]).forEach((forceName) => {
        tempForces[forceName] = simulation.force(forceName);
        simulation.force(forceName, null);
    });
    // You may modify your forces here. Store them to 'tempForces' if you'd like to restore them after dragging.
};

const restoreForces = (simulation) => {
    for (let [name, force] of Object.entries(tempForces)) {
        simulation.force(name, force);
    }
    tempForces = {};
};
```

And then call modifyForces() and restoreForces() when dragging starts and ends respectively. (Adapted from this [observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-lattice?collection=@d3/d3-drag#drag))

```
const start = function(event) {
    modifyForces(simulation); // Modifying
    if (!event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.1).restart();
    }
    event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
};

const drag = function (event) {
    event.subject.fx = event.x;
    event.subject.fy = event.y;
};

const end = function (event) {
    restoreForces(simulation); // Restoring
    if (!event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    }
    event.subject.fx = null;
    event.subject.fy = null;
};

const dragBehavior = d3.drag()
    .on("start", start)
    .on("drag", drag)
    .on("end", end);

node.call(dragBehavior);
```