# Preventing dragging of D3 Network graph nodes from moving other nodes in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I'm using the [vue d3 network](https://github.com/emiliorizzo/vue-d3-network) component for creating a graph with nodes and edges inside my webapp.

Users can dynamically edit the graph by adding and removing nodes and edges. The component allows nodes to be dragged around, by this has an undesired side effect for my application: moving a node causes all the graph to move.

I'm looking for a way to freeze the rest of the graph while moving a node.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460838/stop-moving-other-nodes-while-dragging-one-node-in-d3-forcesimulation) has an answer that accomplishes just that, but it's done with the "vanilla" version of D3 Network. I'm looking for help implementing that using the component I'm currently using.

The main issue I see is there is no `drag` event in vue d3 network. What are possible workarounds?

I'm willing to explore other solutions to implement a dynamically modifiable graph should this not be accomplishable using this component.

Here's the code I'm using right now:
https://pastebin.com/Mg4uYZ1s

Runnable fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pz6nr32m/

Comment: Can you add a [mre] of what you have now? It'll be easier to answer if we don't have to guess about your setup

Comment: @RubenHelsloot thank you for pointing it out. I just added a minimal version of the code I'm using

Comment: Can you turn it into a runnable snippet please?

Comment: Sure, there you go.